# Cannot import CSV to Mysql properly

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am importing data from CSV file into Mysql database. The code works fine but it doesn't insert first line of csv file.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
{
//First we need to make a connection with the database
$host='localhost:3311'; // Host Name.
$db_user= 'root'; //User Name
$db_password= 'root';
$db= 'compared'; // Database Name.
$connect=mysqli_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password,$db);
echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
{
    $csv_file = $filename; // Name of your CSV file
$csvfile = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
$theData = fgets($csvfile);
$i = 0;
while (!feof($csvfile))
{
   $csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile, 1024);
   $csv_array = explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);
   $insert_csv = array();
   $insert_csv['0'] = $csv_array[0];
       $insert_csv['1'] = $csv_array[1];
   $insert_csv['2'] = $csv_array[2];
   $insert_csv['3'] = $csv_array[2];
   $insert_csv['4'] = $csv_array[2];
   $query = "INSERT INTO reviews(id,userid,title, review, rating)
 VALUES('".$insert_csv['0']."','".$insert_csv['1']."','".$insert_csv['2']."','".    $insert_csv['3']."','".$insert_csv['4']."')";
   $n=mysqli_query($connect,$query );
   $i++;
}
fclose($csvfile);
echo "File data successfully imported to database!!";
}
}

?>


<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">File Upload</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="150">
    <p class="help-block">Only Excel/CSV File Import.</p>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Import" value="Import">Upload</button>
</form>
```

this is the data

```
1,2,abc,abc,3
2,3,abc,abcd,5
11,2,abc,abc,3
22,3,abc,abcd,5
```

It inserts from second line and skips the first line. Can anyone fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You perform the first `fgets` outside the loop, and then immediately afterwards another one in the beginning of the loop, thus skipping the first  result.

A [do-while](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php) construct should solve your problem:

```
$theData = fgets($csvfile);
do {
   // Extract data from $theData

   // Insert into the database

   // Get the next line:
   $theData = fgets($csvfile);
} while (!feof($csvfile));
```

Comment: I tried, it does insert a row but everything in there is null